# Generated Excel with ClosedXML does not use the specified font/size during printing

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am creating an offer generator for my company. The generated offer must contains the `General Conditions of Sale` in the second worksheet (the offer details are displayed in the first worksheet). The `General Conditions of Sale` are contained into a word document, so I have to inject them into the worksheet. Last constraint, I have to respect the word's two column layout.

I already have the logic (it can be improved but that's not the point of my question) to extract and insert them into the worksheet. I am using a predefined excel file (with header, footer, column sizes, etc, already defined) and I simply insert the terms in the right merged cells, using [ClosedXml](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML).

My issue concerns the printing of that offer. When I open the generated offer, directly click on `Print` and select `print the entire workbook`, I can then scrolldown in the preview to check if everything is good. When I arrive to the second worksheet, the font and/or the font size are not the ones I specified in the code.

If I open the second worksheet at least once, and then do the former procedure, everything is back to normal and I can print my offer with the right font and font size. I encounter the same issue when I try to export the offer to pdf.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2tr0.png) is the preview when I do not open the second worksheet, with wrong font size. And [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Takiu.png) is the preview if I open the second worksheet at least one before printing, with good font and font size.

Here is my code (notice in the `PrintTerms` function the specification of the font and the size):

```
class Program
{
    const int nbRowByPage = 67;
    const int nbCharByPage = 3650;

    const string generalTermsFileName = "ConditionsGeneralSales_R5.docx";
    const string baseTemplateFileName = "TemplateOffer.xlsx";
    const string generatedExcelFileName = "Offer.xlsx";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Deletes any existing excel file
        var fi = new FileInfo(generatedExcelFileName);
        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }

        using (var workbookDocument = new XLWorkbook(baseTemplateFileName))
        {
            // Fills first worksheet
            // [..]

            // Gets the general terms from the word and injects them into the second worksheet
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(generalTermsFileName, true))
            {
                // Extracts the paragraphs
                var paragraphs = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
                    .Descendants<Paragraph>()
                    .Where(p => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.InnerText))
                    .ToList();

                // Gets the second worksheet
                var conditionsWS = workbookDocument.Worksheet(2);

                // Injects the paragraphs in the worksheets
                PrintTerms(conditionsWS, paragraphs);
            }

            // Saves the excel
            workbookDocument.SaveAs(generatedExcelFileName, true);
        }

        // Opens the generated excel with MS Excel
        Process.Start(generatedExcelFileName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified paragraph into the specified worksheet according this methodology:
    /// - Splits the paragraphs into two columns 
    /// - Fills the excel columns alternatively in order to looks like a two columns word text
    /// - Manage the break page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ws"></param>
    /// <param name="generalTerms"></param>
    static void PrintTerms(IXLWorksheet ws, List<Paragraph> generalTerms)
    {
        var currentParagraphIndex = 0;
        var index = 1;

        while (currentParagraphIndex < generalTerms.Count)
        {
            var nbChar = 0;
            var currentParagraphs = generalTerms.Skip(currentParagraphIndex).TakeWhile(p => (nbChar += p.InnerText.Length) < nbCharByPage).ToList();

            var row = ((int)Math.Ceiling(index / 2d) - 1) * nbRowByPage + 1;
            var column = index % 2 == 0 ? 3 : 1;

            var currentCell = ws.Cell(row, column);
            currentCell.Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Justify);
            currentCell.Style.Alignment.SetVertical(XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Top);
            currentCell.Style.Font.SetFontName("Arial");
            currentCell.Style.Font.SetFontSize(8);

            foreach (var paragraph in currentParagraphs)
            {
                foreach (var run in paragraph.Descendants<Run>())
                {
                    var text = currentCell.RichText.AddText(run.InnerText);

                    if (run.RunProperties.Bold != null)
                    {
                        text.SetBold();
                    }

                    if (run.RunProperties.Italic != null)
                    {
                        text.SetItalic();
                    }

                    if (run.RunProperties.Underline != null)
                    {
                        text.SetUnderline();
                    }
                }

                // Break line
                currentCell.RichText.AddNewLine();
                currentCell.RichText.AddNewLine();
            }

            ws.Range(row, column, row + nbRowByPage - 1, column).Merge();

            index++;
            currentParagraphIndex += currentParagraphs.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

To run this code, you will need to put at the root of the console application the two following files: [terms](https://1drv.ms/w/s!ArmwPwH8RG7yuM4wWE2s_4PqY_53TA) and [template](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArmwPwH8RG7yuM4vNUdgXmf4deMjRg) (check copy if newer in the files properties).

I also tried a lot of combination like:

Setting the workbook global style:

```
workbookDocument.Style
    .Font.SetFontName("Arial")
    .Font.SetFontSize(8);
```

Setting the worksheet style:

```
offerWS.Style
    .Font.SetFontName("Arial")
    .Font.SetFontSize(8);
```

Setting the cell's RichText style:

```
generalTermsCell.RichText
    .SetFontName("Arial")
    .SetFontSize(8);
```

All of this, at the begining or at the ending of the file modification. Nothing works.

I don't think it is a bug into ClosedXML. Excel does not ask me for saving the changes when leaving the app if I had opened the second worksheet. So the generated files do not seem corrupted. It looks like an Excel bug, but may be there is a way in ClosedXML to workaround that?

Comment: Log an issue on the ClosedXML Github page, please. Attach the template as well as the sample code.

Comment: Just did: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/469. Hope we will find the solution :D.